# Why did the class get called twise in this python code?

Tags: python, class

```
import copyreg, pickle

class cars:
    def __init__(self, name):
        self.name = name

def myfunc(x):
    return cars , (x.name,)

copyreg.pickle(cars, myfunc)


test = cars('hello')

print(pickle.dumps(test))
```

1 - Why did the class get called twise in this code ?

```
def myfunc(x):
   #why does it need to be called here too ?
    return cars , (x.name,)

#we already called the class here!!!
copyreg.pickle(cars, myfunc)
```

2 - and why comma in the tuple ?

Comment: comma in 1-element tuple is the only way to distinguish tuple from protected variable

Comment: do you mean i am telling python i want to select the whole element not one piece of the element ?

Comment: what about 'cars' why is it called twise ? we already called it in 'copyreg.pickle' ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following is solely based on the documentations of [copyreg.pickle](https://docs.python.org/3/library/copyreg.html#:%7E:text=The%20copyreg%20module%20offers%20a,constructors%20which%20are%20not%20classes.) and [pickle dispatch_table](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pickle.html#pickle.Pickler.dispatch_table).

> The copyreg module offers a way to define functions used while pickling specific objects. The pickle and copy modules use those functions when pickling/copying those objects. The module provides configuration information about object constructors which are not classes.

This is mentioned in the `copyreg.pickle` docs, it basically tells that the function defined is used when pickling specified objects, here, it is `cars`.

> A pickler object’s dispatch table is a registry of reduction functions of the kind which can be declared using copyreg.pickle(). It is a mapping whose keys are classes and whose values are reduction functions.

This is mentioned in the `pickle.dispatch_table` docs. It basically tells us that `cars` is the class being used as a `key`, and `myfunc` as the reduction function used as its `value`.

Here, to your doubts, `copyreg` is not calling your `class`. It is just creating/editing the `dispatch_table` with the `keys`(class) and `values`(func).

If you are still confused, here's a little experiment, where I added a `print` statement in the function:

```py
import copyreg, pickle

class cars:
    def __init__(self, name):
        self.name = name

def myfunc(x):
    print("This is a test")
    return cars, (x.name,)
    
copyreg.pickle(cars, myfunc)


test = cars('hello')
print(pickle.dumps(test))
```

Output:

> This is a test
> b'\x80\x04\x95!\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x8c\x08__main__\x94\x8c\x04cars\x94\x93\x94\x8c\x05hello\x94\x85\x94R\x94.'

Now, if I just remove the `copyreg.pickle` line. The `dispatch_table` won't be created:

```py
import copyreg, pickle

class cars:
    def __init__(self, name):
        self.name = name

def myfunc(x):
    print("This is a test")
    return cars, (x.name,)

test = cars('hello')
print(pickle.dumps(test))
```

Ouput:

> b'\x80\x04\x95+\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x8c\x08__main__\x94\x8c\x04cars\x94\x93\x94)\x81\x94}\x94\x8c\x04name\x94\x8c\x05hello\x94sb.'

As you can see, the function is not at all triggered. Because the relation is not yet created.

To summarize:

1. `copyreg.pickle` just creates a `dispatch_table` with `class` as `key` and `func` as `value`, and the function defined is used when pickling specified `class`.
2. For the tuple, the comment by `@Jean-FrançoisFabre` is the most suitable.

**EDIT**: Upon more research, here are the addons.

`copyreg.pickle` makes the `myfunc` function act as a reduction function of `cars`. You can skip that part if you define `__reduce__` method in the class itself.

Reduction functions are used by `pickle` for instruction on how to reconstruct the original object from the `pickle` object if it fails automatically.

```py
import copyreg, pickle

class cars:
    def __init__(self, name):
        self.name = name
    
    def __reduce__(self):
        print("This is a test")
        return cars, (self.name,)
        

test = cars('hello')
print(pickle.dumps(test))
```

Output:

> This is a test
> b'\x80\x04\x95!\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x8c\x08__main__\x94\x8c\x04cars\x94\x93\x94\x8c\x05hello\x94\x85\x94R\x94.'

You can skip the `copyreg.pickle` if a `__reduce__` instance is mentioned in your class, and it will act the same.

If you want to know, why these values have to be returned in the function, this [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pickle.html#object.__reduce__) will give you insight on it.

Comment: so the copyreg.pickle() is just used to prin a message when the pickled data get printed ?

Comment: No, I believe you got it wrong. If I simplify it a bit more, I would say, `copyreg.pickle` tells `python` to fire `myfunc` function when `cars` is being pickled.

Comment: I used `print` as an example. You can do whatever you want in `myfunc` and it will perform the action when `cars` is being picked.

Comment: so copyreg.pickle() is sending a dictionary of the the function name and the class name like this : {cars:myfunc} ???

Comment: Yes, it will be stored in the dict-like object. You can refer to the docs mentioned in the answer for more insight depth.

Comment: @unknown I edited my answer with a little more research and it may look more reasonable now.

Comment: oky i will read

Comment: i understand but i have just one question : is pickle.dumps() call the reduce dunder method ?

Comment: Yes, it does. As, `pickle.dumps()` serializes the object which in fact call the `__reduce__` method.

Comment: does pickle.dumps call only reduce ?

Comment: Upon reading the code uploaded in GitHub, `__reduce__`, `__reduce_ex__`, `__getstate__`, `__setstate__` and `__dict__` methods have been used.

Comment: https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/main/Lib/pickle.py